Is there a way to create a timer when a script is run that counts up to a week?
So basically I am trying to make a script that saves input and puts it in another table. Once it does this I need it to create a timer that counts from 0 to a week based off the date and time that was transferred across. I was wondering if anyone knows how this can be done cause I haven't found anything online.
Input Table
Output Table
The date and name would transfer across to the output table and what I am trying to achieve is the timer appearing in the column next to it, on that row.
This is the code I have to transfer the data, but I have nothing to create the timer and am trying to add something into this code to do so.
function saveTax() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var taxForm = ss.getSheetByName('Tax Form');

  var lastRow = taxForm.getLastRow();
  var targetRow = lastRow + 1;

  if (taxForm.getRange('C7').isBlank()){

    taxForm.getRange('C7').setBackground('#ff0000');
    throw new Error('Required Cell is Missing Info. '); 
  }

  else {

    var valuesToCopy = taxForm.getRange('B7').getValues();
    taxForm.getRange(targetRow, 2, 1, valuesToCopy.length).setValues([valuesToCopy.flat()]);

    var valuesToCopy = taxForm.getRange('C7').getValues();
    taxForm.getRange(targetRow, 3, 1, valuesToCopy.length).setValues([valuesToCopy.flat()]);

    taxForm.getRange('C7').setBackground('#ffffff');
  }
}


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand a timer that counts from 0 to a week based off the date and time that was transferred across. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Yeah, of course. What I mean is a timer that informs the viewer how long it has been since the input was done, so if i made it an hour ago the timer would say 1:00:00, to represent an hour. Same with seconds, minutes, days etc. And I want it to end once it reaches 1 week. I hope this is clearer, if not please just inform me

Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand And I want it to end once it reaches 1 week. And, about if i made it an hour ago the timer would say 1:00:00 and 1 week, when the differences are 3 days, what value do you need?

If I understood correctly you need update a sheet column called timer, with time spent since a specific date which comes from other column, right? On this case, you can create a App Script custom formula to the cell and update constantly, here an example:
function getTimeSince(dateCell) {
  // Get the date from the cell
  const dateTime = new Date(Date.parse(dateCell));

  // Check if the date is valid
  if (!dateTime || !(dateTime instanceof Date)) {
    return "Invalid Date";
  }

  // Calculate the time difference in milliseconds
  const now = new Date();
  const diff = now.getTime() - dateTime.getTime();

  // Limit the difference to one week (7 days)
  const limitedDiff = Math.min(diff, 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  // Calculate days, hours, minutes, and seconds
  const days = Math.floor(limitedDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((limitedDiff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((limitedDiff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((limitedDiff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Format the time string with leading zeros
  const formattedDays = days.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const formattedHours = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const formattedMinutes = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const formattedSeconds = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');

  // Return the formatted string (x days hours:minutes:seconds)
  return `${formattedDays} days ${formattedHours}:${formattedMinutes}:${formattedSeconds}`;
}

function createTriggerEvent() {
  // Create a trigger to clear all data from reports at final of month
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('getTimeSince')
           .timeBased()
           .everyMinutes(5) // You can control the interval here
           .create();
}

Then, you'll need run once the createTriggerEvent() on App Script editor to create the trigger, after you can go to the cell and put the new formula =getTimeSince(A1), now it will update the column with the time spent until a week and updates every x minutes.
Does this solve your problem?

I just tried this, it says dateCell.getValue() from line 3 is not a function so an error occurs. Is there something I am missing? Also by chance do you know another way to have a save script that puts the info in that table ignore the timer cell for next row?

@Narukami sorry, it was my mistake, I update the answer, please try again.

You could use the PropertiesService to store the value of the next date to saveTax and the check the current date and run saveTax if today's date valueOf() is greater than the saved date.  Then just update the date in the PropertiesService for the next date.
Something like this:
function saveTax(e) {
  const tjs = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("saveTax");
  let dt = new Date();
  if (tjs) {
    let tObj = JSON.parse(tjs);
    let tdt = new Date(tObj.yyyy, tObj.mm, tObj.dd);
    let tdv = tdt.valueOf();
    
    let dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
    if (tdv >= dtv) {
      let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      let sh = ss.getSheetByName('Tax Form');
      let tr = sh.getLastRow() + 1;
      if (sh.getRange('C7').isBlank()) {
        sh.getRange('C7').setBackground('#ff0000');
        throw new Error('Required Cell is Missing Info. ');
      } else {
        sh.getRange(tr, 2, 1, 2).setValue([[sh.getRange('B7').getValue(), sh.getRange('C7').getValue()]]);
        sh.getRange('C7').setBackground('#ffffff');
      }
      let ndt = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate() + 7);
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("saveTax",JSON.stringify({yyyy:ndt.getFullYear(),mm:ndt.getMonth(),dd:ndt.getDate()}));
    }
  } else {
    let ndt = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate() + 7);  
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("saveTax",JSON.stringify({yyyy:ndt.getFullYear(),mm:ndt.getMonth(),dd:ndt.getDate()}));
  }
}

